# Keeping agents in visual range while moving

Tags: netlogo

I have a model whereby the agents are moving around looking for resources. The individuals move according to:

```
to move
set energy energy -1
fd v
if random 300 = 1 [
ifelse random 2 = 0
[rt 45][lt 45]]
end
```

What I would like them to do in addition to this is keep in visual range of  each other or at least keep a certain group size in range.

In my head this would take the form of `ifelse count turtles in-radius vision < 5 [move-towards-group][move]`

I've tried a few things but the agents end up moving towards each other or losing contact while they enact some other routine causing an error.

I've looked at the flocking model as well but that's a bit too over parameterised for what I'm trying to achieve.

Hope you can help.

EDIT: Based on @JenB's advice I've come up with the following working model. But the agents here tend to swarm and can, on occasion, break off where they get stuck around a group < 5

```
to setup
  clear-all
  reset-ticks 
  crt 20 
end

to go 
 ask turtles [move
   group]
 tick
end 

to move
fd 0.01
if random 333 = 1 [
ifelse random 2 = 0
[rt 45][lt 45]]
end

to group
  let midx mean [xcor] of other turtles in-radius 10
    let midy mean [ycor] of other turtles in-radius 10
    ifelse count other turtles in-radius 5 < 5 [facexy midx midy set color red][move set color blue]
end
```

Comment: the way you have it set up 'in your head' has them all moving towards the group or all moving independently. Could you perhaps calculate the centre of the group and have each turtle do something like 'if I am too far from the centre, move toward centre else move'.

Comment: Hi, I've come up with something based on your advice. The agents tend to swarm now but it's pretty close to what I want.